# How always is returned an array instead of an object as json?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

If my result object have more than one value, return an array as json. But if my result object have only one value, return an object as json. I don't want to return a single object. I always want to return an array.

My code as follow :

```
@Service
@Path("/item")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Scope("request")
public class MyResource {


    @GET
    @Path("/ac")
    public List<ACResult> getACResults(@QueryParam("term") String term) {
        List<MyResultClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

> I use jersey 1.18.3

How can I always return an array instead of object as json when a single object is present?

Comment: If your interface defines that the data is sent as a json array it will always be a json array, even if it contains only a single element. From a development point of view it's easier to just rely on arrays being returned in any case and check the length. Why should the service have different behavior for single elements?

Comment: I guess I was wrong expression. I don't want to return a single object. I always want to return an array. My code have different behavior.

Comment: If you return an arraylist it should also return a json array perhaps jersey optimize something

Comment: Can you try to create a new return class that has the array you want to return and then return object of this class?

Comment: Check this link: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html#d4e926. It discusses your issue in the section '5.2.2.1. Mapped notation'.

Comment: Thanks @Priyesh. It is successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I hava added new class on my project as follow:

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext>  {

    private JAXBContext context;

    private final Class[] types = {MyResultClass.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("myJsonKey").build(), types);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(final Class objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Reference: [here](http://%20jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html#d4e926) or [here](http://sunildattakulkarni.blogspot.com.tr/2012/09/custom-jaxbcontextresolver.html)